# something strange about Win-XP's command shell

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, windows-xp

I wrote the following command in windows XP's command shell and something strange happened:

```
C:\Folder1> copy sample.txt :
```

Because of my typing mistake, I wrote ":" instead of "D:"

... but it copied the sample.txt to somewhere I cant find!

I searched my whole HDD for sample.txt but the only instance of this file is the original one which is in C:\Folder1.

Do you know where ":" path actually is in Win-XP command shell?

You might say ":" is current path and the file has been copied onto itself but look at this:

If you run that command for the first time, this will be the result:

```
1 file copied.
```

but the next time you run that command it will ask you:

```
overwrite sample.txt? (yes/no/all)
```

So if it were writing the file onto itself, both results would have to be the same but they aren't.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why is this question considered off topic? Others concerning "batch" programming, which arguably is the case here, are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data was copied into a NTFS Alternate Data Stream attached to the current directory.

There are tools (e.g. ADSRevealer) that would allow you to verify that `.` has now indeed an ADS attached.

If you type:

```
MORE < :sample.txt
```

you will retrieve the copy of sample.txt.

For more information see e.g. [here](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2012/05/remove-only-one-alternate-data-stream-from-a-file/). Keep in mind that *command line support for ADS in XP is 'immature' at best*.

Comment: So you are saying that "copy sample.txt :" is essentially a shortcut for "copy sample.txt sample.txt:streamname"? Whatever streamname in particular than is. For the live of me I could not find a reference for that on the net (and I don't have a windows box right now to try it out).

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I got it wrong. It is not sample.txt that acquires the ADS, but the directory itself; and it acquires an ADS called sample.txt. Updating answer.